# PyVmomi SNMP with Vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm looking for a way to programmatically register and then receive notifications when Vm migration happens within a Vmware vCenter . During this search I discovered that the vCenter is bundled with a SNMP server . This would also work for me. Therefore and I would be thankful for some code snippets or documentation pointing on how to achieve this.

Thanks